# Relational Algebra - Mistake in the quiz?

Tags: relational-algebra

I've just done a mini test and scored 9/10, however, from my understanding, I think this question is incorrect.

Here is the only question which I don't understand how it can be correct:

[image]

So I joined up the relations and get this:

```
A | R.B | S.B | C | D 
1 |  2  |  2  | 4 | 6   //this meets theta-condition R.A<S.C AND R.B<S.D
3 |  4  |  4  | 6 | 8   //this meets theta-condition R.A<S.C AND R.B<S.D
3 |  4  |  4  | 7 | 9   //this meets theta-condition R.A<S.C AND R.B<S.D
5 |  6
```

So the potential answers are:

```
1,2,2,4,6
3,4,4,6,8
3,4,4,7,9
```

But, as seen in the question I do not have matching-solution for any of these and I made an educated guess and concluded that there was a mistake in the paper... or did I make the mistake?

Comment: Hint: R.B = S.B wasn't one of the join conditions.

Comment: @Pseudonym I thought the theta-join was a bit like the natural join enforcing equality on the attributes of the same name? OR should I have taken both the relations, combine all tuples and return a relation with only the combinations which pass the theta test - in this case `,1,2,4,6,8` would be perfectly valid since it passes theta -condition? Is my understanding corrrect?

Comment: Theta-join joins on the declared condition, no more and no less. See, for example, https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/311/lecture04.html

Comment: @Pseudonym Add an answer so that we can have one less unanswered question on the site? :-)